# Laravel Eloquent Search in JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel, eloquent

I'm having an issue with searching in a JSON column. Laravel 8.x and MySQL 5.7.x

Given the following column `'industry_focus'`, I'm trying to match and return all records containing any of the values

`["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8"]`

My query looks like this:

```php
$related = Broker::query()
->where('broker_name', '!=', null)
->where('is_active', '=', true)
->where('state', '=', $state->code);

foreach ($same_industries as $key => $value) {
    if ($key === 0) {
        $related->whereJsonContains('industry_focus', (string) $value->id);
    } else {
        $related->orWhereJsonContains('industry_focus', (string) $value->id);
    }
}

$related = $related
->limit(10)
->get();
```

And it produces a raw query looking like this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM `brokers`
WHERE `broker_name` IS NOT NULL
    AND `is_active` = 1
    AND `state` = 'NY'
    AND json_contains(`industry_focus`, '\"2\"')
    OR json_contains(`industry_focus`, '\"3\"')
    OR json_contains(`industry_focus`, '\"4\"')
    OR json_contains(`industry_focus`, '\"5\"')
    OR json_contains(`industry_focus`, '\"6\"')
    OR json_contains(`industry_focus`, '\"7\"')
    OR json_contains(`industry_focus`, '\"8\"')
    OR json_contains(`industry_focus`, '\"9\"')
    OR json_contains(`industry_focus`, '\"10\"')
    OR json_contains(`industry_focus`, '\"11\"')
    OR json_contains(`industry_focus`, '\"12\"')
    OR json_contains(`industry_focus`, '\"13\"')
    OR json_contains(`industry_focus`, '\"14\"')
    OR json_contains(`industry_focus`, '\"15\"')
    OR json_contains(`industry_focus`, '\"16\"')
limit 10
```

Unfortunately, this is wrong and is returning all records ignoring any and all conditions. I think there's a parenthesis missing before the first `AND json_contains` and a closing one at the end? Is this a bug, or am I missing something. Is there a better way to write this?

**EDIT:** Ok, so I managed to fix this myself somehow looking at examples elsewhere. This is what works for me:

```php
$related = Broker::query()
    ->where('broker_name', '!=', null)
    ->where('is_active', '=', true)
    ->where('state', '=', $state->code);

$related->where(function ($query) use ($same_industries) {
    foreach ($same_industries as $key => $value) {
        if ($key === 0) {
            $query->whereJsonContains('industry_focus', (string) $value->id);
        } else {
            $query->orWhereJsonContains('industry_focus', (string) $value->id);
        }
    }
});

$related = $related
    ->limit(10)
    ->get();
```

Comment: what is `$sameIndustries`? `whereJsonContains` can take an array of values

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to review boolean algebra. There's an operator precedence between `AND` and `OR` that is biting you in this case.

```
A AND B OR C OR D
```

Is equivalent to

```
(A AND B) OR C OR D
```

But what you need is:

```
A AND (B OR C OR D)
```

To get this in a boolean expression, you need to use the parentheses explicitly to override the natural operator precedence.

What else would make this query easier is what I tell many people who are using JSON in MySQL:

**Don't use JSON in MySQL** if you mean to use the elements inside the JSON document as discrete data elements, and search for them with SQL expressions.

In this case, you have a multi-valued attribute `industry_focus`. The normal way to implement a multi-valued attribute is to make a second table, and store one value per row.

```
CREATE TABLE broker_industry_focus (
  broker_id INT NOT NULL,
  industry_focus INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (broker_id, industry_focus)
);
INSERT INTO broker_industry_focus VALUES (123, 7), (123, 11);
```

Once you do that you can search more easily:

```
SELECT *
FROM brokers AS b
JOIN broker_industry_focus AS f 
    ON b.id = f.broker_id
WHERE b.broker_name IS NOT NULL
    AND b.is_active = 1
    AND b.state = 'NY'
    AND f.industry_focus IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
```

You might also like my presentation [How to Use JSON in MySQL Wrong](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-use-json-in-mysql-wrong).

Comment: Thank you for the concise explanation -- I will look into it and try to follow better practices. For now, I just needed a quick fix, and managed to do it somehow. See my edit above.